# Referencing a pointer of array in a struct with ctypes

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, ctypes

According to what I learned from references and reading the the [official ctypes tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html). I can recreate and reference the elements of a C/C++ structure in Python.
So I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    BVHTree *tree;
    float epsilon;
    float (*coords)[3];
    unsigned int (*tris)[3];
    unsigned int coords_len, tris_len;
    int *orig_index;
    float (*orig_normal)[3];
} PyBVHTree;
```

And ctypes I tried to do so:

```
import ctypes
class PyBVHTree(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 8
    _fields_ = [
    ("ob_base",      ctypes.py_object), #PyObject_HEAD
    ("tree",         ctypes.c_void_p),
    ("epsilon",      ctypes.c_float),
    ("coords",       ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * 3)),
    ("tris",         ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint * 3)),
    ("coords_len",   ctypes.c_uint),
    ("tris_len",     ctypes.c_uint),
    ("orig_index",   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
    ("orig_normal",  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * 3)),
    ]
```

I refer to the python object this way:

```
c_tree = PyBVHTree.from_address(id(tree))
```

The "epsilon" I can get without problem, but when I try to get the "coords" ... CRASH !!!

I guess I'm not referencing the pointer of array in the right way.
How do I reference a pointer of arrays with 3 elements in ctypes?

Comment: `ctypes.py_object` is a pointer. `ob_base` should be a `ctypes.Structure`  with `_fields_ = (('ob_refcnt', ctypes.c_ssize_t), ('ob_type', ctypes.c_void_p))`.

Comment: Your array pointer definitions are fine. You dereference the pointer to get the array using, for example, `coords_array = c_tree.coords[0]`.

Comment: Thank @eryksun :). Worked perfectly. I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @eryksun, my mistake was that I was referencing a pointer as PyObject_HEAD.
The right way:

```
import ctypes

class PyObject_HEAD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("ob_refcnt",    ctypes.c_ssize_t),
    ("ob_type",      ctypes.c_void_p),
    ]

class PyBVHTree(ctypes.Structure):
    #_pack_ = 8
    _fields_ = [
    ("ob_base",      PyObject_HEAD),
    ("tree",         ctypes.c_void_p),
    ("epsilon",      ctypes.c_float),
    ("coords",       ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * 3)),
    ("tris",         ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint * 3)),
    ("coords_len",   ctypes.c_uint),
    ("tris_len",     ctypes.c_uint),
    ("orig_index",   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
    ("orig_normal",  ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * 3)),
    ]
```

Comment: Does the C declaration use `__declspec(align(8))` (MSVC) or `__attribute__ ((aligned (8)))` (gcc)? If not, why do you have `_pack_ = 8` instead of using the natural alignment?

Comment: MSVC does not use it. Always I specified ´_pack_ = 8´ but without knowing why. I was afraid that the code stayed incompatible to other OS.

Comment: In a 32-bit process the natural alignment in this case would be 4 bytes.

Comment: But this code works in both the application for 32-bit and for 64-bit. I got it wrong? Anyway I'll leave the natural alignment.

Comment: I don't think it was causing problems because ctypes still uses the 4-byte alignment in the 32-bit case. I just thought it was an unusual thing to do.